# UK visit visa 2 years from Egypt

Tags: uk-visitor-visa

I am planning to apply for the visit visa for the second time. It was issued for me once before for 6 months, and I have travelled twice with the same visa and returned on time.

This time I want to submit for a 2-year visit visa from Egypt to visit my British husband. We have been together since 2012 in Egypt and he first travelled to the UK on September 2017 and stayed there.

He got a job recently earning £15000 annually (that’s why I don’t qualify for a spouse visa) and I am currently working in my home country in a multinational company with a fixed contract and medical cover worldwide.

I will submit:

- my pay slips for the last 6 months;
- my 6-month bank statement;
- his tenancy agreement.
- my HR letter;
- an invitation letter;
- his job offer;
- his passport;
- my credit card;
- medical cover;
- our marriage certificate.

Are there any missing documents? Will they approve this visit visa? Are there any documents especially required for the **2-year visit visa**?

I will travel to my meet with my husband and his family in the UK. His father and mother are based in **Egypt** (although his mother is Egyptian and his father is British), so I will submit their flight tickets.

I need to travel:

- in October for a ten-day family gathering: my husband, his parents, and his brother will be there;
- in March for 15 days for our anniversary;
- to visit my husband frequently.

My family lives in Egypt and I have a job in a **multinational company** so those are the ties mentioned.